# g++ compiler not using precompiled header *.h.gch

Tags: c++, header-files

this my **log.cpp**
file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void log(){
    cout << "OMG, nothing is working...";
}
```

this my header file : **log.h**

```
void log();
```

this's my **main.cpp** file

```
#include "log.h"

int main(){
    log();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to precompile the header file I use this command
`g++ log.h` I get **log.h.gch** file
then I compile the **main.cpp** file using
`g++ main.cpp`
I get this Error :(

```
/tmp/cc9YGzwo.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `log()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status[![help me please][1]][1]
```

Comment: You don't compile header files, you compiler cpp files. Compile `g++ -c log.cpp` and then link the `log.o` when you compile your main.

Comment: .... and _if_ you compile header files, see it as a service that your toolkit provides.

Answer (score 2):

The header declared `void log()`, main wants to use it, but it's missing the implementation. Link `log.o` to main.

```
g++ -c log.cpp
```

Then

```
g++ main.cpp -o main log.o
```

---

Output:

> OMG, nothing is working...